# Error starting Glassfish 4.1.1 from Netbeans

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, netbeans-8

Starting Glassfish 4.1.1 from Netbeans I get the next exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to org.glassfish.tyrus.server.TyrusServerContainer
```

This is my log:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
objc[5414]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
may 09, 2016 7:55:16 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFORMACIÓN: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
may 09, 2016 7:55:16 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
ADVERTENCIA: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
may 09, 2016 7:55:16 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
ADVERTENCIA: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
may 09, 2016 7:55:16 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner startBundles
ADVERTENCIA: Can not start bundle file:/Users/japochino/glassfish4.1.1/glassfish/modules/core.jar because it is not contained in the list of installed bundles.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@2d14e1 in service registry.
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=/Users/japochino/glassfish4.1.1/glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=/Users/japochino/glassfish4.1.1/glassfish/lib/templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=/Users/japochino/glassfish4.1.1/glassfish/lib/templates/logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=/Users/japochino/glassfish4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/logging.properties
Información:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (build 1)
Información:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Información:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Información:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Información:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Información:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Información:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Advertencia:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Información:   JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]
Información:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 100ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Advertencia:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Información:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Advertencia:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Información:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
Información:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   Java security manager is disabled.
Información:   Entering Security Startup Service.
Información:   Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
Información:   Security Service(s) started successfully.
Información:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
Información:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
Información:   Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
Información:   Created virtual server server
Información:   Created virtual server __asadmin
Información:   Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
Información:   Virtual server server loaded default web module 
Información:   WELD-000900: 2.2.13 (Final)
Información:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final
WARN:   WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PostActivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
WARN:   WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PrePassivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
Información:   WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration@580e26bb]
Información:   Registering WebSocket filter for url pattern /*
Información:   Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.12 ( 20150720-0848 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.12@14885) para el contexto '/chp'
Información:   Monitoring jndi:/server/chp/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
Información:   Running on PrimeFaces 5.2
Grave:   WebModule[/chp]Exception starting filter WebSocket filter
java.lang.InstantiationException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:5329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5974)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:406)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:243)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:326)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:374)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to org.glassfish.tyrus.server.TyrusServerContainer
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.init(TyrusServletFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:131)
    ... 28 more

Información:   Constructor Loging
Información:   Loading application [chp] at [/chp]
Información:   Loading application chp done in 45.554 ms
Información:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (1) startup time : Felix (54.002ms), startup services(47.639ms), total(101.641ms)
Información:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
Información:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://192.168.1.37:8686/jndi/rmi://192.168.1.37:8686/jmxrmi
Información:   Listening to REST requests at context: /management/domain.
Información:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@232cce0 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@6e106680.
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.12 ( 20150720-0848 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.12@14885) para el contexto ''
Información:   Loading application [__admingui] at [/]
Información:   Loading application __admingui done in 3.547 ms
```

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Hey. If you select the trace, and use ctrl+k, it will format your exception as code. May be helpfull to understand what is your problem. On the other hand, add to your question more information about, wich is your server version, why, where and how are you trying to cast  a class provided by glassfish to one provided by tomcat library, and all kind of stuff that you think it can helps

Comment: Thanks for the ctrl+k trick. I have edited the post and now it's more clear. I'm not aware of that casting. I don't do it at least consciously

Comment: Look for this jar tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar, and avoit it to be on your app's claspath. May be the trick

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried everything such as looking up for unused ports, reconfiguring ports in the xml file, reinstalling Netbeans and glassfish several times.

I then uninstalled Google Drive application which I suspected would be blocking the ports (It was not showing up in the activity monitor or by the lsof command in terminal). After uninstalling, it worked !

So try to remove all the third party cloud storage applications such as Drive, Box, DropBox, etc and see if it works or not.